# Cloudfront issue streaming certain video files with VP6F and MPEG audio

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Greetings fellow amazonians

We have certain f4v files from webtvinteractive.com that are not working from a streaming distribution. The cloudfront diagnostic tool indicates the file is not found but from a download distribution they play all ok fine ??

When inspecting the codec the only difference we see is that the audio is encoded as  MPEG audio layer 1/2/3 (mpga) instead of AAC (mp4a)

Also noticed that VP6F is used but that is a Abobe proprietary codec so it should stream all ok from Flash Media Server

Here is the test tool url:
http://d1k5ny0m6d4zlj.cloudfront.net/diag/CFStreamingDiag.html

s3dbhkulzq9ndp.cloudfront.net
teaser.f4v (ok)
EM2_H264.f4v (NOT ok)

StreamLen Response: 0   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received an answer from AWS team member
Posted by: RonS@AWS
Posted on: Oct 10, 2011 7:29 AM 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=284676

Hi, I downloaded both of your video objects and ran flvcheck (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_AdminGuide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d119f29261b7-7ffc.html) against them.

The teaser.f4v is apparently OK according to flvcheck, but EM2_H264 gets this:
11-10-10 07:10:25 Error: -26 File appears to be FLV with wrong extension. EM2_H264.f4v

If I rename the file to have a .flv extension, I get "Found backward timestamp".

I suspect the FMS software we're using will have the same complaints about that file that flvcheck does.

flvcheck is available for download here (you'll need to register with Adobe): http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/tool_downloads/